# iOS UIButtons having positive or negative properties

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uibutton

I can't find a UIButton property to assert that the button is positive (ok, submit, etc.) or negative (cancel, delete). I expected there to be a standard way to make a red or green button.

Do I need to make UIButtons red/green by customizing their view? I'd like the button to be red text/green text to comply with iOS 7's new style, but was hoping that in iOS 6, the button would adapt (display a red/green background color)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything like that built in to `UIButton`, you have to customize them yourself.

The closest there is to this in the SDK, is you can set a destructive button on `UIActionSheet` that is tinted red. But more generally, in iOS 7, cancelation isn't really associated with the color of the button anymore. If for example you want to present an alert view with two buttons, it's customary for the continue button to use regular text, and the cancel button to use bold faced text.

Comment: Accepted for the info on iOS 7's new guidelines

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it programatically. This is the best way to customize stuff. If you want to make it really cool, mess around with the layer property.

```
UIbutton *submitBtn = [UIbutton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[submitBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[submitBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
// hook it up to a function
[submitBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(submit:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//add it to subview
[self.view addSubview:submitBtn];
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the button tint gives me the effect I was looking for:

```
deleteButton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Still undecided on whether or not I will use this technique. User716216 made a good point about iOS 7's new guidelines for buttons.